# Share and manage rc files (or config files) between mltiple projects

Tags: node.js, npm, config

I'm working on different projects based on node, and one thing I always have to do is create the configuration files in all the projects since you all share a lot of configuration, for example, in all projects I use commitlint, lint-stage, husky, eslint, nodemon, and typescript and other settings.

How could I share all these settings in all projects and if I update any of them, update them in all projects?

The first thing that occurs to me is to create a npm packet with all the configurations, and several scripts, that copies / updates these configuration files in the root directory of the project where user is, something like

```
> myscript update
> myscrpt init
```

Another option would be to use the configurations programmatically, that is, instead of using a .rc use a .js, but this would force me to manage the dependencies in each project and create a .rc file that uses the configuration of the js file which is in the configuration package.

Another option is to create a github repository as a template, but if I update this repository, the projects I have created using this template are not updated, right?

What do you think is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Even though git submodules seem to be discouraged lately, I think it's the most reasonable choice (assuming all of your projects are git-based): https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

In your case, you'd have a 'common' repository with configuration, eg. `configuration` and two projects: `projectA` and `projectB`. Both of them would have the submodules added:

```
git submodule add <your_git_repo_server>/configuration
```

**Please notice**, however, that submodule refers to a particular **commit** (not a branch or tag - commit). You always have to take big care of synchronizing your dependencies correctly.

Comment: And how you will manage the package dependencies like commitlint, lint-stage, husky, ...? and as I understand, you can not use a submodule in the root directory, no?

Comment: I can only suggest symbolic links. So, you'd create a symbolic link within your repo's root which would point into the configuration file from `configuration` submodule.